# Odoo /web/content returns 404 but works fine in browser

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-12

I am using odoo 14 and I think I am missing some permission to access the web/content/path. If I put the URL directly in the browser the image returns fine but if I use it through an ajax request or put the URL directly in img tag it returns 404. Is odoo restricting by domain name? I tried to request from localhost and a domain still it returns 404.

```
<img src="http://odoo_ip:8069/web/content/product.template/76/image_128">
```

I tried to set proxy_mode to true but instead of the actual image, I am getting this.[image]

Comment: add `proxy_mode = True` in your conf file hope it will help. secondly i think image while fetching get confused because there are many databases running on same port and ip

Comment: @AdamStrauss I have edited my question, the URL returns the image icon instead of the actual image. If I passed the URL directly in the browser it returning the image fine. and second I have only one database.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is: you have multiple databases in your instance.

I had the same problem, and I fix it by (remove other databases, or add another config file to load a single database).